# Python 3 - How to return all rows as a dict using csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Listed below is my code to read rows and return one row based on the key value (a specific column i.e. player). How do I return the rest of records?

```
with open('Players.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        key = row.pop('PLAYER') #this is my key column
        if key in result:
            pass
        result[key] = row

print (result) #printd (Player and all attributes)
```

Comment: How do you mean *return the rest of records*?

Comment: I need to load the rest of records in another function.

Comment: Can you prepare [MCVE]? Sample (2-3 lines, 2-3 columns) CSV file, and expected `result` dict?

Comment: What is `result`? You are iterating over all the rows of the CSV, so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to look at`row.keys()` and `row.items()`